# 9 patch image draws background color

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

I have an image containing arrow drawn on white color background. I'm decoding it as follows.

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow);  
Bitmap bm;  
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),     Config.ARGB_8888);  
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);   
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());  
drawable.draw(canvas);  
bm = bitmap;
```

When bitmap 'bm' is drawn on canvas, I can still see white color background. Where as in case of normal png, it works just fine.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this image?

Answer (score 1):

The PNG format supports the transparency channel while BMP doesn't. So if you are using a .bmp or .jpeg file as your arrow drawable, you will get a full rectangular copy of it drawn on the canvas. So my advice is to find a .png version of an arrow.

Comment: I have this image in png format only. I even observed that this image opacity is OPAQUE.. Could it be wrong?

Comment: If you need to have a Bitmap from your resource I would suggest using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res, int id) instead of using the Drawable class.